# find Network card Manufacturer from macaddress.io MAC json database

Tags: json, database, jq, string-matching

Is there an efficient way to query macaddress.io json Mac database using jq to find a network car manufacturer.
the database is freely available at https://macaddress.io/database-download (select json + download

```
  "oui": "00:50:C2:73:E",
  "isPrivate": false,
  "companyName": "Quantec Networks GmbH",
  "companyAddress": "Rieselwiese 1 Vienenburg Niedersachsen 38690 DE",
  "countryCode": "DE",
  "assignmentBlockSize": "IAB",
  "dateCreated": "2007-05-14",
  "dateUpdated": "2015-08-29"
}
```

For a DeLL Computer, I can query like this:
`cat macaddress.io-db.json |jq 'select(.oui|test("14:18:77"))'`
Unfortunately, for the above record, there are multiple company name matching 00:50:C2 and you need to give more digit to have the unique correct answer.

The ugly approach is to loop on the full MAC address removing one digit until query succeed.

So for a DeLL computer, this will loop 6 times before we get a result:
Let's take the 14:18:77:34:23:12 MAC as example:

```
1st query: 14:18:77:34:23:1 => no answer
2nd query: 14:18:77:34:23 => no answer
3rd query: 14:18:77:34:2 => no answer
4th query: 14:18:77:34 => no answer
5th query: 14:18:77:3 => no answer
6th query: 14:18:77 => we get the DeLL record:
{
  "oui": "14:18:77",
  "isPrivate": false,
  "companyName": "Dell Inc",
  "companyAddress": "One Dell way Round Rock 78682 US",
  "countryCode": "US",
  "assignmentBlockSize": "MA-L",
  "dateCreated": "2015-06-13",
  "dateUpdated": "2019-07-01"
}
```

I wonder if there is a smarter approach that would return the best match given a full MAC.

For example: 14:18:77:34:23:12 MAC would match the 14:18:77 record (DeLL)

And 00:50:C2:73:E3:27 MAC would match 00:50:C2:73:E record and not 00:50:C2:73:F record.

Any idea/tips/jq command to accomplish the above "soft/smart" matching?

(Goal is, given a full MAC (in upper or lower case), to retrieve the companyName field or "Unknown" (or "") if not found.)

Note that oui field are unique and there are no subset (if XX:YY:ZZ:TT exists, you cannot have XX:YY:ZZ (but you can have XX:YY:ZZ:UU)). Knowing that, means that the longest match is unique (single record).

Answer (score 1):

The key to a reasonably efficient solution is to begin by collecting the plausible candidates using `inputs` with the -n command-line option of jq. With this in mind, we can write:

```
# Winnow recursively
def winnow($s; $i):
  if ($s|length) < $i then . # no further winnowing
  else $s[0:$i] as $ss
  | map(select(.oui | startswith($ss))) as $result
  | if ($result|length) == 0 then . # prior
    elif ($result|length) == 1 then $result
    else $result | winnow($s; $i+1)
    end
  end;

def bestMatch($s):
  $s[0:1] as $first
  | [inputs | select(.oui | startswith($first))]
  | (select(length>0) | winnow($s; 2)) // "Unknown"
  | if type == "array" and length == 1 then .[0] else . end
  ;
```

### Examples

```
bestMatch("14:18:77:34:23:12")
```

yields the JSON object with .oui == "14:18:77";

```
bestMatch("00:50:C2:73:E3:27")
```

yields the JSON object with .oui == "00:50:C2:73:E"

Comment: Nice! almost there... now you need to add handling of "no match" case and it'll be ready for upvoting :)

Comment: It’s already there - see "Unknown" in the program. That’s not a comment!

Comment: yep, I see it. but try a mac with an illegal oui, e.g.: `01:0A:E4:73:E3:27`

Comment: @Dmitry - The requirements seem to insist on partial matches.  In your example, the initial "0" matches 18160 objects.  So maybe some clarification of the requirements is needed?

Comment: sure, but given the MAC OUI by definition is 3 bytes - it could not be partially matched - it' a _unique_ identifier, the "partial" requirement is only applicable to the lower 3 bytes  of the MAC (at least that makes sense from the networking point of view). but I'm not insisting - it would be up to OP to insist on it :) I'll upvote your solution now

Comment: Excellent. Though with invalid MAC, the code will return many results (all wrong).